# Can i override a page title of portlet with JSP

Tags: jsp, struts, portlet, page-title

I have a remote portlet page with some title 'a'. When the action is successful and forwarding to a JSP page i need to change the page title as 'b'. Can someone help me in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Page title or Portlet title? Can you provide more detail of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

For WebSphere Portal:

As the implementation of the standard API portlet container does not support dynamic titles for WebSphere Portal, dynamic titles do not work, even if the remote portlet is written according to the IBM portlet API. But I assume this is applicable to other portlet containers as well (Not sure)

Are you using WPS?

Comment: JSR-286 portlets allow this. RenderResponse.setTitle http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/RenderResponse.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)